# Windows server 2012 ignores static routing

Tags: windows, vpn, routing

BIG UPDATE: I was blind I see now that route 172.17.50.1 has netmask 255.255.255.255 and so it point to single host! But now I cannot understand how can I ping 172.17.50.10 because there is not route to reach it.

I have a windows server 2012, added an openvpn vpn.
Then I added a static route to 10.1.0.0/24 using the vpn as gateway.
As you can see below, windows ignores the route and goes to internet via default route.
I have tried also with firewall disabled. 
The only thing I can think about is that the 10.1.0.0/24 route is not related to any local network interface.

What can I do?

Here is the route print:

```
===========================================================================
 Interface List
 18...00 ff 44 8f 66 99 ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
 13...00 50 56 a2 18 ea ......Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection #2
 12...00 50 56 a2 18 eb ......Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection
 1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 16...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 17...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 14...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
 19...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
 15...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     109.168.95.1    109.168.95.39    266
         10.2.4.0    255.255.255.0         On-link          10.2.4.2    266
         10.2.4.2  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.2.4.2    266
       10.2.4.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.2.4.2    266
     109.168.95.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     109.168.95.39    266
    109.168.95.39  255.255.255.255         On-link     109.168.95.39    266
   109.168.95.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     109.168.95.39    266
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      172.17.50.0    255.255.255.0      172.17.50.2      172.17.50.1     30
      172.17.50.0  255.255.255.252         On-link       172.17.50.1    286
      172.17.50.1  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.17.50.1    286
      172.17.50.3  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.17.50.1    286
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       172.17.50.1    286
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link          10.2.4.2    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     109.168.95.39    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.17.50.1    286
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.2.4.2    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     109.168.95.39    266
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
         10.1.0.0    255.255.255.0     172.17.50.10       1
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     109.168.95.1  Default
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
 14   1011 ::/0                     2002:c058:6301::1
 14   1026 ::/0                     2002:c058:6301::c058:6301
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 14   1010 2002::/16                On-link
 14    266 2002:6da8:5f27::6da8:5f27/128
                                    On-link
 18    286 fe80::/64                On-link
 18    286 fe80::fd4b:756f:5d03:195f/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 18    286 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Trace

```
C:\Users\Administrator>tracert 10.1.0.1

Tracing route to 10.1.0.1 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  3.95.168.109.host.static.ip.kpnqwest.it [109.168.95.3]
  2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  cr2-ge1-47-cal3.mil.kpnqwest.it [94.141.0.50]
  3    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  cr2-ge1-8-cal1.mil.kpnqwest.it [94.141.0.45]
```

Comment: Are you adding the route manually, or selecting "Use default gateway on remote network" in OpenVPN and running as administrator? 10.0.0.0/8 should not be routed on the public internet, I am curious to see how far that trace route goes

Comment: Can you tracert `172.17.50.10`?

Comment: Why didn't you configure the route in openvpn, instead of adding it in Windows?

Comment: Also, why would you have `172.17.50.10` as a gateway, if that one in turn has `172.16.50.2` as gateway again? (from the `172.16.50.0/24` route)

Comment: I have not tracert 172.17.50.10 but I can ping it.

Comment: I have not configured the route in openvpn because the openvpn server is on windows and, as far as I know, openvpn can push routes to clients, not to server

Comment: I have not seen the 172.17.50.2 gateway. But openvpn is multi client, infact I have another gateway 172.17.50.6 for 10.2.2.0/24

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the gateway for this network is not reachable - try to ping 172.17.50.10

Comment: Gateway is reachable I ping it everyday and it works.
BTW: I have also tried to enable rip in windows and in the other server and they happily shared routes but again it did not work.